# How to check if CALayer exists

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, calayer

I have a CALayer which animates (moves) off-screen on the y axis.
After it's off-screen i'm doing a `[myLayer removeFromSuperLayer]` so its gone from the view and does not go back to start position.

While the layer is still in the view it can be paused and resumed by pushing a toggle button and this works all fine.

The only thing is that after the `[myLayer removeFromSuperLayer]` has run my app crashes.
This is caused by the fact the button is trying to pause or resume the layer which doesn't exist anymore.

How can i check if  the layer is removed or still in the view?

I thought something like this for the pause part of my toggle button:

```
if (self.myLayer == nil)
    {
        // here i want to add the layer again
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:myLayer];
        // immediately pause it
        [self pauseLayer:myLayer];

    }

else

    {
        // just pause no need to create the layer again because it's still there 
        [self pauseLayer:myLayer]; 
    }
```

As you might suspect the `self.myLayer == nil` is not the way to do it, but what is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Removing a layer from its superlayer will not cause the layer to become nil, which is why your `self.myLayer == nil` check is not working.  However, you could easily set the field to nil when you remove it, like:

```
[self.myLayer removeFromSuperLayer];
self.myLayer = nil;
```

Of course, if you need to add it again after that then you'd need to either reassign the layer to `self.myLayer` (if you have a reference to it that you're keeping somewhere else) or create a new instance of the layer from scratch.

Comment: Oke found another way so it doesn't go back to start position.     anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards; now i don't even have to check anymore.